# Is there a setting that controls the default shape of vectors?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector, cell

When my colleague and I run the same code he is getting a row cell array (`1x10`) while I am getting a column cell array (`10x1`). Is there a setting or preference which we may have that specifies the default structure (tall vs wide) of a cell array?

We have already compared settings and output, and are both using R2018a.

The mismatch in shape causes a `Index exceeds array bounds` error.

Comment: If I transpose the cell array dd=dd' the code works fine and he begins to experience my problems.

Comment: No, there is no such setting. Please share a minimal version of the code that creates this cell array. Maybe one of you has one of the functions shadowed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is best not to assume the shape of inputs but instead to *make sure* it is what you expect (see: [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)). Two ways forward in your case (of vectors):

1. Shape checking:

   ```
   assert( isrow(A), 'Input must be a row vector!');
   ```
2. Shape manipulation:

   ```
   % if you need it to be a column:
   colA = A(:);
   colA = reshape(A, [], 1);

   % if you need it to be a row:
   rowA = A(:).';
   rowA = reshape(A, 1, []);
   ```

In the "checking" alternative you would be alerted that something about the shape of the input is not right, whereas in the "manipulation" alternative (which I prefer) it would just handle whatever shape you give it.

**See also:** [`validateattributes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html).